# scala list addall method

Tags: list, scala

This is my java code,

```
  public void test( List<Map> courses)
    {
    ....

    List<Map> data = (List<Map>) response.getBody();
    courses.addAll(data);

    pageNo = pagination(response.getHeaders());
     if(pageNo!=null) 
     {
            params.put("pageNo", pageNo);
            pAccountCourses(params, courses);
      }
    }
```

How to convert it into scala List[AccountCourses] , so that i can add **courseList** into **accountCourseslist**

```
def test(courseList: java.util.ArrayList[AccountCourses]) {
......
//getting json data
var pageNo: String = null
val body = response.body
val json = parse(body)

var accountCourseslist = json.extract[java.util.ArrayList[AccountCourses]]
    accountCourseslist.addAll(courseList)

 if (pageNo != null) {
            params.put("pageNo", pageNo);
            test(accountCourseslist);
          }
}

case class AccountCourses(id: Int) //case class
```

how to perform addAll operation of list in scala?

Answer (score 1):

1. How to convert `java.util.ArrayList[AccountCourses]` to scala list?

   use `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` :

   ```
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
   val javaList = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()
   val scalaList = javaList.asScala
   val scalaImmutableList = scalaList.toList // will return immutable copy
   ```
2. How to perform addAll operation of list in scala?

   Use `++=` if it is mutable collection or `++` on immutable list:

   ```
   scalaList ++= List(1,2,3,4,5) // will also update javaList
   val result = scalaImmutableList ++ List(1,2,3,4,5) // will return new copy
   ```